GeoNetwork 3.10 error after failed attempt to upgrade to 4.2
I tried to get back to GeoNetwork 3.10 with a PostgreSQL database backend.
However even if the specifc metadata are being shown: Call to api, the GUI fails.
In geonetwork.log I now see a lot of these messages, but what is the metadata document index?
java.lang.NullPointerException
2024-04-11 11:25:30,397 ERROR [geonetwork.datamanager] - The metadata document index with id=4893 is corrupt/invalid - ignoring it. Error: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
2024-04-11 11:25:53,611 ERROR [jeeves.service] - Exception executing gui service : java.lang.NullPointerException

